# passing list of lists to a function

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list `[0.2, [1, 1.3], [1, 0.5, 2.1] ...]` and need to pass this list as an argument in a function and I should be able to access elements in the called function, kindly help with code or hints to do this. Thanks in advance

```
def func(list):

    #calculate opt_p using list    
    return(opt_p)

def metric(metric, K, N):              

      opt_p=[]
      creating a sequence such that(alpha is my variable name) 
      alpha_0 = [0.2]   has one element
      alpha_1 = [1, 1.3] two elements
      alpha_2 = [1, 0.5, 2.1] three elements ... upto alpha N suchthat last element has N  elements

      temp=func(alpha) #HERE IS THE ERROR *Invalid syntax
      opt_p.append(func(temp))

def main():

    metric(12, 5, 8)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: You never defined `opt_alpha`. Just pass `[alpha_0, alpha_1,...]`.

Comment: @RAFIQ: for future use, you can format your code by selecting it and hitting the curly brace button -- {} -- above the text box, or by typing control-K.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, you're missing some key variables.

Comment: Where is opt_alpha coming from?

Comment: I think this is not the entire code judging by a previous edit version of his [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9099574/5).

Comment: Apologies to all, pls check now, im not able pass the list to func(), also alpha =[alpha_1, alpha_2 ...]

Comment: Don't repeat your question. Read the comments to your previous question and take them to your heart. It seems that you would profit the most by reading the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and learn the basics.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm understanding something wrong, but looks like you forgot the

```
opt_alpha = [alpha_0, alpha_1, alpha_2]
```

line just before the error.
When the func is invoked, the opt_alpha in not known.

By the way you miss the `i` value.

My advice is: try to read the code once more. The first think that's being run is `if __name__`. Then the main function. Then the metric and then the func. Follow your variables. If you're not used to debugging in your mind, take a pen, some paper and write all the values of variables step by step. In a minute you'll see, where were the mistakes.

EDIT:

Due to commment:

Look at this example.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [3, 4, 5]
>>> l = [a, b, c]
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> def f(l):
...     for element in l:
...             print element
...     print "--", l[2][1]
... 
>>> f(l)
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
-- 4
>>>
```

There is no philosophy of passing list of lists to function. You simply... do it.

Comment: pls understand that the alpha list has been created and take alpha and just tel me how to pass it to a function(func here) and and access alpha list in side func

Comment: @Gandi Sounds like a Taoist philosophy to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a syntax confusion. If alpha is the variable then it should be set like so

```
 alpha = [[] for x in range(0,3)]
 alpha[0] = [list]
 alpha[1] = [other list]
 ...

 func(alpha)
```

and as noted you have not defined 'i' so it will be created in the function call.

Comment: say you are generating numbers by some logic 0.2, 1, 1.3, 1, 0.5, 2.1 and need to group them such that first set has one element, second set has 2 elements third has 3 so on. I represented them as [0.2, [1, 1.3], [1, 0.5, 2.1] ...] and pass them to a function

Comment: that way the first list is not a list, it needs to be [[0.2],[1,1.3],[1,0.5,2.1]] Otherwise the fist element of the list is just the number and if you try to index it you will get an error.

Comment: how else can we implement this logic to pass these grouped values to function other than lists?

Comment: I think lists are a great way of doing this. You could use tuples instead but why don't we try to figure out what's making this difficult for you instead. Maybe you could ask another question?

Comment: ok in the example you have mentioned can you use single variable rather than a,b,c using loop, to generate same list again. this is because length is variable.

Comment: You mean want a list of the structures [[none],[none,none],[none,none,none]]? Up to a set number of lists?

Then you need code like
[[0] * x for x in range (1,4) ] 
That will generate a list that looks like
[[0],[0,0],[0,0,0]]
You can change 0 to whatever you want the default value to be

Comment: i guess i can manage with this and would do the job. thanks a lot Russ.